# A question about the choice of a special harmonc spinor

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory

Let $X$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $H$ be the kernel of generalized Dirac operator $D$ on $L(S)$, where $S$ is the Dirac bundle. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ and $K\subset \Omega$ be a neighborhood of $K$. Fix an $\varepsilon>0$ and choose an $\varepsilon$-dense subset $\{x_m\}_{m=1}^d$ of $K$, i.e., every point of $K$ is within distance $\varepsilon$ of some $x_m$.

**My question: If we suppose $\dim H>d$, why there exists an element $\sigma\in H$ such that $\|\sigma\|=1$ and $\sigma(x_m)=0$ for all $m=1,\cdots,d$?**

Could you please help me with the details? Thank you!

Comment: It appears that you are reading some paper about solutions of a generalized Dirac equation.  If you want help understanding the paper, you should at least tell us which paper you are reading.  At the very least, it will help us understand the notation you are using.  (For example, what do you mean by $L(S)$ and what do you mean by $\| \sigma\|$?)

Comment: @RobertBryant Yeap，it is the paper of Gromov Lawson in 1983.

Comment: @RobertBryant $\|\sigma\|=\int_X <\sigma_1,\sigma_2>$, where $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are compactly supported in the space $\Gamma(S)$ of smooth of Dirac bundle $S$. And $L(S)$ is the completion of $\Gamma(S)$  with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Could you give me some help? Beside this question, I'm also confused with a theorem, this is the linking https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407049/green-operators-associated-with-dirac-operators-on-a-complete-riemannian-manifol?noredirect=1#comment1043768_407049

Comment: http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1983__58__83_0.pdf